# Firebird SQL command for reindexing a column

Tags: sql, firebird

Wondering what the SQL command is to re-number a column in firebird, so each row for that column reads:

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 instead of 1, 2, 4, 6, 10, 11..

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Btw: re-index is not really the right term, renumber would probably better covert it.

Comment: Given the currently posted answer by Edin (which is a possible answer, but not how I interpreted your question), you might also want to more clearly explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: Apologies, I just simply want to renumber a column so that there is no gaps between the numbers. Basically go through each row and sync it with a counter or something so the column reads 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 not 1,3,6,7,9,11,16.

Comment: Ok, so you want to renumber the values in a single column? That is not really easy to do, so first consist if you really need it.

Comment: I think I know how to achieve it but not sure how to write it. Basically a variable needs to be created and assigned to the column after each row is processed/looped through and then the variable incremented ready to be assigned to the next row.. but have no clue how to achieve this in SQL

Comment: I'll post a solution later, probably tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created a simple example to demonstrate this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE renumber_example (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

I populated this table with some discontinuous numbers:

```
INSERT INTO renumber_example (id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO renumber_example (id) VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO renumber_example (id) VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO renumber_example (id) VALUES (10);
INSERT INTO renumber_example (id) VALUES (15);
```

To renumber you can use an [`EXECUTE BLOCK`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-execblock) or a stored procedure:

```
SET TERM #;
EXECUTE BLOCK
AS
    DECLARE newId INTEGER;
BEGIN
    newId = 1;
    FOR select id from renumber_example order by id AS CURSOR reorder DO
    BEGIN
        UPDATE renumber_example SET id = :newId WHERE CURRENT OF reorder;
        newId = newId + 1;
    END
END#
SET TERM ;#
```

Note: `SET TERM` is not actually part of the Firebird SQL language, but it is part of most SQL clients for Firebird (e.g. isql, FlameRobin). If you execute this directly from your own application using a client library (eg fbclient.dll, Jaybird, Firebird .net provider etc), then you must leave out the `SET TERM` statements.

With Firebird 3 and higher you can also do this with a single [`MERGE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref30/fblangref30-dml-merge.html) statement that uses the [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref30/fblangref30-windowfuncs-rankfuncs.html#fblangref30-windowfuncs-row-number) window function:

```
MERGE INTO renumber_example as target
    USING (
        SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) as newId 
        FROM renumber_example
    ) AS source
    ON target.id = source.id
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET target.id = source.newId;
```

However, as I mentioned earlier in my comments: please consider carefully why you want to do this and if you really need to. If the numbers are meaningless then you shouldn't care about the gaps, and if they do have meaning, then chances are those values also have meaning outside your system in which case renumbering 'breaks' the external truth. Also, if these values are primary or unique keys with foreign keys then you need to ensure that all foreign keys are `ON UPDATE CASCADE`.

Comment: Appreciate the time and knowledge used to answer this in such great detail, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to update column position you can use this:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER [COLUMN] colname POSITION <newpos>
<newpos>  ::=  an integer between 1 and the number of columns
```

http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-alter-table.html